# Spark - how to flatmap sorted RDD using a stateful mapper?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

Basically I have an RDD/DataFrame containing series of events (with some categoryId). They are timestamped and are ordered by time.
What I'd like to do is to scan all those events within each category while keeping/updating some state which remembers if some event was seen. Some example:

- user logs into amazon (record new session id, timestamp)
- user adds item to basked (increment basket size to 1)
- user performs checkout (increment money spent, to output rdd add item: sessionId+start_timestamp+number if items + money spent)
- user add something else to the basket
- performs checkout -> add next item to the output rdd

So pretty much I'd like to do a flatMap with a stateful mapper (which remembers previous items). The mapper could have a map of "states" by categoryId. But what is there are millions of categories? Is there some better way than just sorting by category+timestamp?
I'd also need to ensure that whole category is on a single node. Should I partition by category in this case? I'm not sure if millions of partitions are good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your question is rather generic you'll get a generic answer. Unless you have a good reason for not to you should use [Data Frames](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/02/17/introducing-dataframes-in-spark-for-large-scale-data-science.html) and [Window Functions](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html).

The first of the above will give you all the benefits of the [Catalyst Optimizer](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/04/13/deep-dive-into-spark-sqls-catalyst-optimizer.html). The second one should provide the operations you may to handle your data as you've described:

- `PARTITION BY` - partition data by category
- `ORDER BY` - order by timestamp
- `FRAME` (`ROWS` / `RANGE`) - optional restrictions on window size
- actual [functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) to perform desired operations

**Side note**:

> I'm not sure if millions of partitions are good idea.

No, it's not a good idea at all, but partitioning by some key doesn't mean you need the same number of partitions as the number of unique keys:

```
import org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner
val rdd = sc.parallelize(
   (1 to 10).flatMap(k => (1 to 100).map(_ => (k, scala.util.Random.nextInt)))
).partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(2))
```

In above example you have 10 different values but only 2 partitions.

Comment: Makes sense. I guess it's time to upgrade to 1.4.